# Play mp3 sound files in asterisk

Tags: mp3, asterisk, playback

I have installed asterisk on my centos system but asterisk only supports wav,gsm but not mp3 .how can i play mp3 sound file in asterisk
I have searched a bit and found that to play mp3 we have to install format_mp3.so module and mpg123   I have installed format_mp3.so module but i dint install mpg123

So my question is that can i install mpg123 manullay likke **yum install mpg123** or do in have to install asterisk again? and install mpg123 during asterisk make command as given in [this](http://www.asteriskguru.com/tutorials/mp3player.html)
 and to play mp3 do i nee to install any othe module or anything?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of asterisk you are using? Do you see any load error of format_mp3 module when asterisk start? It is possible that your module can't load without mpg123, and it will work after installation.

Additionally it is good practice to convert sounds to format you are using for calls, because if you don't, asterisk will convert them in fly every time

Comment: thanks for the reply,i am using asterisk-11.11.0 and i dont see any errors onloading format_mp3.But now i have installed mpg123(yum install mpg123).I just want to ask do i need anything more to play mp3 and is mpg123 work if its not installed with asterisk

Answer (score 2):

If you building asterisk from source, you have do

```
make menuconfig
```

and select mp3 module.

If you installing from rpm usualy it list all required modules.